# Add custom layout page to Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I've created a custom module in order to use a custom layout for the homepage of website. I've selected the custom layout from the dropdown view in pages/cms but for some reason I am getting a blank screen...

Here is my modules config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Layout>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </My_Layout>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <one_column_home module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>One Column Home</label>
                    <template>page/1column-home.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>1 Column Home</layout_handle>
                </one_column_home>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_layout>
                    <file>layout.xml</file>
                </my_layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <layout translate="label">
        <label>1 Column Home</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-home.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </layout>
</layout>
```

and the 1column-home.phtml I've removed the CSS in order to customise it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>

<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Module XML app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Layout>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Page />
        </depends>
    </My_Layout>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Anyone able to spot what I've done wrong please give me the heads up!

Comment: Do you have an module activation file under app/etc/modules ?

Comment: @Su123 Yes, I created a module for it... See update!

Answer (score 1):

The `layout_handle` cannot have spaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <one_column_home module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>One Column Home</label>
                    <template>page/1column-home.phtml</template>
                    <!-- This value is important -->
                    <layout_handle>one_column_home</layout_handle>
                </one_column_home>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

A layout file must use this handle.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <!-- 'layout' is not nested inside 'layout' -->
    <one_column_home translate="label">
        <label>1 Column Home</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-home.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </one_column_home>
</layout>
```

Comment: I've made your changes but I still get a blank screen

Comment: @user2157 Your code shows `<layout_handle>1 Column Home</layout_handle>` which is not a valid handle.

Comment: @benmarks Got it! <layout>1 column home</layout>

Comment: "1 column home" will not work as a layout handle because it has spaces in it.  You can only have spaces in the label.